# Is there a way to retrieve a function's arguments from the outside of the function

Tags: javascript, frontend

I know the title may sound confusing.

Consider a snippet like this

```
function foo(){
  ...
}

var arr = [foo(1),foo(2),foo(3),...]
```

I want to find a way to retrieve those arguments from the `arr` array, to get something like this
    `[1,2,3,...]`

Can someone help me?

Comment: So you want to see a history of every argument that's been passed to a function? It would probably be easier just to record the arguments before passing them in.

Comment: Hum... This is weird request, can we have an example ? Why do you want that ? Basically you call all the functions so you should be able to know before

Comment: Simple answer is that this is impossible - that's how scope works. What is the actual problem which gives rise to the question?

Comment: you can return the function argument

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context. E.g. it would be easy to pass this code example to a parser and extract the arguments from the call expression, but I guess that's not what you actually want. Which overall problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @RobinZigmond impossible ? No. But not like that

Answer (score 1):

Usually this type of operation is done the other way around. You can declare

```
var arr = [1,2,3,...]
var foos = arr.map(n => foo(n))
```

Now you have access to both the original arguments and your foo results.

Comment: i like this approach. clean and easy.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers suggest, it might be better to store arguments you pass before passing them.

Alternatively the easiest way to fill the array would be to return previously passed args like this:

```
function foo(arg) {
   //does things
   return arg;
}

let arr = [foo(1), foo(2), ...]
```

If the function is used to return something else you might return several things by returning an object like this:

```
function foo(arg){
   //does things
   return {
     thing: thing,
     arg: arg
   };
}

let arr = [foo(42).arg, ...]
```

Which is kind of passing the same information back & forth, yet, as I understood it's exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

If you try to get list of **ONE single** args:

```js
    function foo() {
      /* .. */
      return arguments[0]
    }
    console.log([foo(1), foo(2), foo(3)]) // [1,2,3]
```

But this is not working for multiple:

```js
    function foo() {
      /* .. */
      return arguments[0]
    }
    console.log([foo(1), foo(2,3), foo(4,5)]) // [1,2,4]
```

And this one will put every args on an array

```js
    function foo() {
      /* .. */
      return arguments
    }
    console.log([...foo(1), ...foo(2,3), ...foo(4,5)]) // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If you don't want to use `return` statement: This example will put ALL arguments on a global array.

```js
let all_args = []

function foo() {
  Array.from(arguments).forEach(a => {
    all_args.push(a)
  })
  /*..*/
}

foo(1)
foo(2)
foo(3,4)
console.log("args:", all_args);   // [1,2,3,4]
foo(5)
console.log("args:", all_args);   // [1,2,3,4,5]

all_args = [] // Reset
foo(1,1,2,3,5)
console.log("args:", all_args); // [1,1,2,3,5]
```